# PHP - Internal Server Error - I haven't done anything to the website

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

My Client is currently hosting the website that I built for them with Dotster.com, and they recently moved over to entirely new servers or what not, and redirected the DNS for the domain name (they told her in an Email), and ever since then this error has been occurring (constantly), I get the `Internal Server Error` along with the regular messages, but here are my error logs:

I have no idea why this would be an issue?

**Edit**

The new servers must have broken my `.htaccess` code.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]

php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
```

Comment: That's the access log. Look in the error log to get the exact problem

Comment: That's what I thought, but these are the only logs that I can find.

Comment: No `error.log` anywhere? It should be...

Comment: For error log search in global apache2.conf (on linux probably in /etc/apache2/) and in your vhost config file (in linux probably /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/)

Comment: Well there are, however They haven't been modified for 2 weeks, and this problem began about a week ago.

Comment: are there any redirect rules in an htaccess file? In my experience 99% of 500 Errors are either a formatting issue that breaks the htaccess file, or an improper redirect that results in an infinite loop which very quickly exceeds the Apache redirect limit...

Comment: Your server is `dedicated`, `vps` or `shared`? If shared, maybe the only `ADM` can solve, because it is probably the `memory` configuration, there may be some flaw that is overloading the servers. It can also be some of the apache module that is not installed on the server. Try putting **"IF"** in all modules. Eg. `<IfModule MODULE_NAME.c>...</IfModule>`

Comment: Agree with @WebChemist . Post the `.htaccess` file for the DocumentRoot directory; the problem is either there or in the virtual host definition file (unlikely, since that's usually set up by the hoster, which *should* have run regression tests).

Comment: Hey, it turns out it is something to do with my .htaccess file, the new servers must have broken my file, I have posted the contents of it above.

Comment: The error log file would still be the best source for finding out what the problem is *exactly*. It *must* be somewhere

Comment: @DylanCross Is the server running PHP in CGI mode or as a module?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655027/setting-display-error-php-configuration-in-htaccess)