# Setting display_error PHP configuration in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to disable display_errors from `.htaccess`, but if I just paste this into the `.htaccess` file, the entire site crashes:

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
```

Comment: Your host might not allow you to set ini variables in htaccess

Comment: What is the error message in the logs when you have the code in .htaccess?

Comment: If you mean crash as in 500 error, it means you are running as CGI and not as Apache module, do what @dev-null-dweller has instructed with a .user.ini do a phpinfo() to see if the directives mentioned here http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php are enabled and the filename you are to use is the same as well.

Comment: Sorry, I get a server error. The same as when I have a typo. I need to know the EXACT syntax down to the periods and semi-colons.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if php is compiled as apache module and you have privileges to change those.

If you are using php >= 5.3, there is better solution: create `.user.ini` file in your document root and use normal ini syntax to customize your config.